# Coordinate error in pstricks

Tags: pstricks

I wish I could draw some diagrams with pstricks. But I have a coordinate problem when I draw figures. For example, when I draw a rectangle using `\psframe (0,0) (2,2)`, the rectangle does not appear to start from coordinates (0,0) but from a slightly higher value as you can see on the copy below

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-labo}
\begin{document}
\psset{unit=0.5cm}
\psgrid[subgriddiv=1, griddots=10, gridlabels=5pt, gridwidth=0.5pt](-2,-2)(6,6)
        %\colorlet{myfill}{brown!60}
        \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](0,0)(0.25,13)   

        
        \end{document}
```

With the same code in overleaf, the problem does not recur

Where does the problem come from ?

thanks in advance`

Comment: Can you provide a complete minimal document that replicates this? I can't replicate this myself with an up-to-date TeXLive 2021.

Comment: my guess would be that you are adding space tokens where you do not want them but as you have given no indication of the input  hard to guess.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : I added my code

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I think I understood where the difference comes from: it comes from the command ```\colorlet {myfill} {brown! 60}``` but I don't understand why (I added my code in the initial post)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put it into a `pspicture` environment!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-labo}
\begin{document}
\psset{unit=0.5cm}
\pspicture
\psgrid[subgriddiv=1, griddots=10, gridlabels=5pt, gridwidth=0.5pt](-2,-2)(6,6)
\colorlet{myfill}{brown!60}
\psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](0,0)(0.25,13)   
\endpspicture
        
\end{document}
```

However, `fillcolor=brown!60` makes live easier ...

Comment: +1 for Herbert with `fillcolor=brown!60` makes live easier ...

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a space after the color let, which you can comment out:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-labo}
\begin{document}
\psset{unit=0.5cm}
\psgrid[subgriddiv=1, griddots=10, gridlabels=5pt, gridwidth=0.5pt](-2,-2)(6,6)
        \colorlet{myfill}{brown!60}%%%%%
        \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](0,0)(0.25,13)   

        
\end{document}
```